# How to configure RemoteSiteSetting and CsPTrustedSite metadata?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, remote-site-settings, csp

I am creating a Lightning Web Component which calls an external API to show the data on work.com Command Center.

I want to distribute this component on AppExchange as a managed app. I found the reference metadata config for `RemoteSiteSetting` and `CspTrustedSite`.

How do I include the `RemoteSiteSetting` and `CspTrustedSite` in the config of the package?

Current component meta file: `myComponent.js-meta.xml`

```
  <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Health Hero Wellness Score</masterLabel>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Configs I want to include:

```
  <RemoteSiteSetting xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>Used to get organization Wellness Score from Health Hero</description>
    <disableProtocolSecurity>false</disableProtocolSecurity>
    <isActive>true</isActive>
    <url>https://my_url_to_whitelist.com</url>
  </RemoteSiteSetting>

  <CspTrustedSite xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>Used to get organization Wellness Score from Health Hero</description>
    <endpointUrl>https://my_url_to_whitelist.com</endpointUrl>
    <isActive>true</isActive>
    <isApplicableToConnectSrc>true</isApplicableToConnectSrc>
    <isApplicableToFontSrc>true</isApplicableToFontSrc>
    <isApplicableToFrameSrc>false</isApplicableToFrameSrc>
    <isApplicableToImgSrc>true</isApplicableToImgSrc>
    <isApplicableToMediaSrc>false</isApplicableToMediaSrc>
    <isApplicableToStyleSrc>true</isApplicableToStyleSrc>
    <context>All</context>
  </CspTrustedSite>
```

What should be the location of the above config in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the RemoteSite Settings and CSP(Content Security Policy Trusted Site) are packageable as a part of the Managed package.

You will go to the package manager and add these components as well. Subscribers upon installation will get this in their orgs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mohith